# encoding empty array in JavascriptSerializer using custom JavascriptConverter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using a custom converter to encode an object model. On the client, I need an empty array but I don't want to include this array in the object model on the server because the array is only used client-side.

This is what I have:

```
public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
{

    MyObjectModel TheObjectModel = obj as ObjectModel;
    Dictionary<string, object> OutputJson = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    OutputJson.Add("MyEmptyArray", new Array()); // not working here
```

What do I need to put instead of `new Array()`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ArrayList` instead of `Array`.  (Also, I think you meant to write "OutputJson" instead of "Output".)

```
OutputJson.Add("MyEmptyArray", new ArrayList());
```

---

Note the error message:  `Array` is an abstract class.

> Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Array'